# Teradata Correlated subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, max, teradata

I'm facing an issue since 2 days regarding this query :

```
select distinct a.id, 
a.amount as amount1, 
(select max (a.date) from t1 a where a.id=t.id and a.cesitc='0' and a.date<t.date) as date1,
 t.id, t.amount as amount2, t.date as date2
 from t1 a
inner join  t1 t on t.id = a.id and  a.cevexp in ('0', '1' )  
and exists  (select t.id from t1 t
where t.id= a.id and t.amount <> a.amount and t.date > a.date) 
and t.cesitc='1' and t.dafms='2015-07-31' and t.date >='2015-04-30' and '2015-07-31' >= t.daefga 
and '2015-07-31' <= t.daecga and t.cevexp='1' and     t.amount >'1'
```

Some details, the goal is to compare the difference in valuation of assets (id), column n2 (a.amount/ amount1) is the one which needs to be corrected.

I would like my a.mount/amount1 being correlated with my subquery 'date1' which is actually not the case. Same criterias have to be applied to find the correct amount1.
The outcomes of this query are currently displaying like this :

```
Id    Amount1    Date1        id    amount2    date2
1     100       04/03/2014    1     150       30/06/2015
1     102       04/03/2014    1     150       30/06/2015
1     170       04/03/2014    1     150       30/06/2015
```

the Amount1 matches with all Date1 < date2 instead of max(date1) < date2 that's why I have several amount1

Thanks in advance for helping hand :)
have a good day !

Comment: Can you add some example data (possibly DDL and INSERTs) and the expected result? IMHO you should be able to get that result with OLAP-functions avoiding both the EXISTS and the Scalar Subquery. And what's your Teradata release?

Comment: Hi dnoeth, there is only one possibly result per date. here Amount1 reffers to the second part of the query (from EXISTS statement) which indicates t.date > a.date. I would like to implement the following rules : t.date > max (a.date) to get the most recent date with the most recent amount. I'm using Teradata 14.10.0503. I'm gonna give you an example of data.
Thanks for replying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the previous row's data using a Windowed Aggregate Function, there's no `LEAD`/`LAG` in Teradata, but it's easy to rewrite.

This will return the correct data for your example:

```
SELECT t.*,
   MIN(amount) -- previous amount
   OVER (PARTITION BY Id
         ORDER BY date_valuation, dafms DESC
         ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS prev_amount,
   MIN(date_valuation) -- previous date
   OVER (PARTITION BY Id
         ORDER BY date_valuation, dafms DESC
         ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS prev_date
FROM test5 AS t
QUALIFY cesitc = '1' -- return only the current row
```

If it doesn't work as expected you need to add more details of the applied logic.

Btw, if a column is a DECIMAL you shouldn't add quotes, `150` instead of `'150'`. And there's only one recommended way to write a date, using a *date literal*, e.g. `DATE '2015-07-31'`

Comment: yep, it works perfectly, i'm gonna try to adapt your query to find all the ID which matches to my query conditions. I let you know :)
Thank for your support !

Answer (score 0):

The final query :

```
SELECT a.id, a.mtvbie, a.date_valuation, t.id,
MIN(t.amount) -- previous amount
OVER (PARTITION BY t.Id
     ORDER BY t.date_valuation, t.dafms DESC
     ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS prev_amount,
MIN(t.date_valuation) -- previous date
OVER (PARTITION BY t.Id
     ORDER BY t.date_valuation, t.dafms DESC
     ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS prev_date
FROM test5 t
inner join test5 a on a.id=t.id
where t.amount <> a.amount and a.cesitc='1' and a.date_valuation > t.date_valuation and a.dafms ='2015-07-31' and another criteria....
QUALIFY row_number () over (partition by a.id order a.cogarc)=1
```

Comment: You should edit your original query to add this info.

This data doesn't match your original query: `date1` is probably `date` in your SELECT. Plus there's a column `deafga` which is missing in your DDL.

What's the actual data types, VARCHAR for DATEs? Then it's also doesn't match your SELECT.

And finally, what's the expected result and why?

Comment: I edit my post, sorry it's the first time :) Is it better for understanding now ?

Comment: It's still confusing, but I think I know what you want :-)